# Get value of log file in python from variable

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I am getting the source code of page in one variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Intro</title></head><body><a href='/name=t1.304.log'>Test</a>.  </body></html>
```

I want to extract `t1.304.log` out of above line.
I am using print `log_name.split(".log",1)[0]` but it is fetching me the first whole part.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by extracting the desired string out of the line? Do you want to extract any string that looks like "something.log"?

Comment: yes any string which ends with .log. and it will come only once

Comment: By "only once", do you mean only the first matching substring? Or do you want to make sure the string only contains one match?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't parse the HTML with an [HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Intro</title></head><body><a href='/name=t1.304.log'>Test</a>.  </body></html>"
>>> BeautifulSoup(data).a["href"].split("=")[-1]
't1.304.log'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do it in a quick way you can use the `split()` function documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
log_name.split("'")[1].split("=")[1]
```

However to do it in a reusable way look into a tool like [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

**Edited to add**

Based on your comments you could do this:

```
print(log_name.split(".log",1)[0].rsplit("=",1)[1] + ".log")
```

Comment: that is not a string, i am taking value from source code

Comment: import urllib

url = 'http://www.google.com"
logfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
logfile = logfile.read()
logfile= logfile.split(".log",1)[0].rsplit("=",1)[1] + ".log")

Answer (score 0):

```
   import re
    st = " <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Intro</title></head><body><a href='/name=t1.304.log'>Test</a>.  </body></html>"

    mo = re.search('(t\S*log)', st)

    print(mo.group())
```

**output**

```
t1.304.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression (with the `re` module), assuming your string variable is `page_source`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.*=(.*.log)', page_source)
['t1.304.log']
```

This gives you a list of all matching "*.log" substrings.

But, be warned, apparently it is not advisable to use regular expressions to parse HTML - see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

In fact, don't do this, use [alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32812707/1728179).